# What is that @{} mean in .cshtml?

Tags: c#, razor, client, client-server

Don't be wrong, I know it's c# code inside it. I am new at Asp.Net Core Web apps with Razor pages. And I try to understand if what's inside @{} is working on server or not. I'm not really sure how to separate server and client sides. Where's the client? And where's the server? .cshtml is client and controllers\models are server, I though. But what if I use C# code inside .cshtml then I unite two sides or what? Please, can anybody explain it to newbie? Thanks.

P.S. Just starting, no tomatoes, please =)

Comment: It's processed on the server to generate an html file and send that file to the client

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#razor-code-blocks

Comment: @Rafalon so if I use @{} inside .cshtml file, it automatically processing as server-sided code? Thank you, I got it

Comment: @Claire - See the answer below: it will be processed server-side everytime a request reaches the server for the specific page, but still, the client will receive html only

Answer (score 2):

@{ } is for writing C# code inside a .cshtml razor page.
All the C# code written in .cshtml is compiled only 1 time per request, you can't use it to interact with user in client-side.